# Open Select using Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is there a way to open a select box using Javascript (and jQuery)?

```
<select style="width:150px;">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc arcu nunc, rhoncus ac dignissim at, rhoncus ac tellus.</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

I have to open my select, cause of IE bug. All versions of IE (6,7,8) cut my options.
As far as I know, there is no CSS bugfix for this.
At the moment I try to do the following:

```
var original_width = 0;
var selected_val = false;

if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
    $('select').click(function(){
        if (selected_val == false){
            if(original_width == 0)
                original_width = $(this).width();

            $(this).css({
                'position' : 'absolute',
                'width' : 'auto'
            });
        }else{
            $(this).css({
                'position' : 'relative',
                'width' : original_width
            });
            selected_val = false;
        }
    });

    $('select').blur(function(){
        $(this).css({
            'position' : 'relative',
            'width' : original_width
        });
    });

    $('select').blur(function(){
        $(this).css({
            'position' : 'relative',
            'width' : original_width
        });
    });
            
    $('select').change(function(){
        $(this).css({
            'position' : 'relative',
            'width' : original_width
        });
    });

    $('select option').click(function(){
        $(this).css({
            'position' : 'relative',
            'width' : original_width
        });
    
        selected_val = true;
    });

}
```

But clicking on my select the first time will change the width of the select but I have to click again to open it.

Comment: checkout http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found another way fixing this problem.
Here is the fix:

Please give me feedback! I'm kind of proud on myself ;)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
            select_init();
    }
});


function select_init () {
    var selects = $('select');
    for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
        _resizeselect.init(selects[i]);
    }
}


var _resizeselect = {
    obj : new Array(),
    init : function (el) {
        this.obj[el] = new resizeselect (el);
    }
}

function resizeselect (el) {

    this.el = el;
    this.p = el.parentNode;
    this.ht = el.parentNode.offsetHeight;
    var obj = this;
    this.set = false;

    el.onmousedown = function () {
        obj.set_select("mousedown");
    }
    el.onblur = function () {
        obj.reset_select("blur");
    }
    el.onchange = function () {
        obj.reset_select("change");
    }

}

resizeselect.prototype.set_select = function (str) {

    if (this.set) {
        this.set = false;
        return;
    }

    this.el.style.width = "auto";
    this.el.style.position = "absolute";
    this.p.style.height = this.ht + "px";
    this.p.style.zIndex = 100;
    this.set = true;
    this.el.focus();
}

resizeselect.prototype.reset_select = function (str) {
    this.el.style.width = "";
    this.el.style.position = "";
    this.p.style.height = "";
    this.p.style.zIndex = 1;
    this.set = false;
    window.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
var myDropDown=$("#myDropDown");
var length = $('#myDropDown> option').length;
//open dropdown
myDropDown.attr('size',length);
```

and this to close:

```
//close dropdown
myDropDown.attr('size',0);
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this is pretty old and answered, but this worked for me in Safari and iOS UIWebView - I have it hidden, but want it to show and open when a different button is clicked.

```
$('#select-id').show().focus().click();
```

Comment: And thank you! After 6hrs of trial and error this did the trick on a stack JQM/Cordova/FastClick !!!

Comment: On Chrome, when the select box is the target of the keydown event, this works like a charm!  Thanks for the tip, Matt H

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `click`, you could use the `mousedown` handler to capture the `mousedown` event.
`mousedown` fires before `click`, so you could call `stopPropogation` to break the event queue.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
dropDown = function (elementId) {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById(elementId);
    try {
        showDropdown(dropdown);
    } catch(e) {

    }
    return false;
};

showDropdown = function (element) {
    var event;
    event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

Then call the function:

```
dropDown('elementId');
```

Comment: you could also use the trigger() command if your using JQuery.

Comment: The jQuery trigger doesn't work. You should just try to create event like the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**NO** jQuery solution.

```
<SCRIPT>
    function toggleDropdown(element){
        if(element.size == 0) {
            element.size = element.length;
            element.focus();
            }
        else element.size = 0;
        }
</SCRIPT>
```

Found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due).

Comment: This opens the dropdown, but doesn't allow subsequent arrow key navigation in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to return true from your event handlers (click, blur, etc.) so after your handler executes, the browser continues to propagate the event and open the select.

It is similar with href links, if they have an onclick handler and the handler returns false, the link is not followed (the browser stops the event after your handler executes).

**EDIT:** Based on your comment and answer, it seems that your handler gets the first chance to execute only after the browser decides to open the box.
I suggest that you try the `focus` event handler, it might get a chance to run earlier than the `click` handler and perhaps before the browser actually opens the box. It is also more consistent (applies both to mouse and keyboard navigation).

Comment: I tried to return true after my event actions - without success.
It seems like the select opens up on first click, but it does not change its styles. After releasing my mouse, the select will close and add the styles. So I have to click again to open it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I feel the pain of this limitation in IE - bleh!
Just thought I'd also share this as it seems to be working for me. I've taken almost the same approach, but on a per select element. In my case I know which lists could have long data.

Instead of making the select elements absolute, I've kept them inline and wrap them in a DIV with a hidden overflow as appearance needed to be  consistent, also it only applies this 'hack' if it is IE and the expanded width is greater than the current width.

To use this for all select boxes you could use something like:

```
$("select").each(function(){ 
        $(this).IELongDropDown(); 
     });
```

Or obviously on a per element bases by id.
Here's the jquery plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.IELongDropDown = function(cln) {
        if (jQuery.browser.msie) { //only IE has problems with long select boxes
            var el = this;
            var previousWidth = el.width();
            var divWrapper = "<div style='padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden;width:"+ previousWidth +"px'></div>";
            el.wrap(divWrapper);
            var newWidth = el.width("auto").width();
            el.width(previousWidth);
            if(newWidth > previousWidth) {
                el.bind("mousedown", function(){ return el.width("auto").focus(); }); 
                el.bind("blur", function(){ return el.width(previousWidth); });
                el.bind("change", function(){ return el.width(previousWidth); });
            }
        }
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to set my CSS in a CSS file and then "addClass" but even so, your code (portion)

```
   $('select').blur(function(){ 
        $(this).css({ 
            'position' : 'relative', 
            'width' : original_width 
        }); 
    }); 

    $('select').blur(function(){ 
        $(this).css({ 
            'position' : 'relative', 
            'width' : original_width 
        }); 
    });
```

seems to be a duplicate

I would make it:

```
$('select').blur().css({ 
        'position' : 'relative', 
        'width' : original_width 
});
```

Not sure you really even need the .blur() here what with the .change() event (try taking it out see see if that addresses your issue...I use select often on IE and do not seem to have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The mousedown event is raise before the click event :

1. first mousedown raise -> set the width to 'auto' (if the state of the dropdown is 'close')
2. click raise -> store in a var the state of the dropdown : 'open'
3. We select a value, the second mousedown is raised : nothing to do
4. click raise -> we need to restore the original width of the dropdown and change the state of the var to : 'close'

The blur and change event are needed to close the dropdown if the user clicked outside the dropdown.

Here the complete solution with Brendan's code :

```
(function ($) {
var open = {}
$.fn.IELongDropDown = function (cln) {
    if (jQuery.browser.msie) { //only IE has problems with long select boxes
        var el = this;
        var id = el.attr('id');
        var margin = 2; //Need to set a margin however the arrow is cut
        var previousWidth = el.width() + margin;
        var divWrapper = "<div style='padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden;width:" + previousWidth + "px'></div>";
        el.wrap(divWrapper);
        var newWidth = el.width("auto").width();
        el.width(previousWidth);
        if (newWidth > previousWidth) {
            el.mousedown(function () {
                if (!open[id]) {
                    el.width("auto");
                    el.focus();
                }
            });
            el.click(function () {
                if (!open[id])
                    open[id] = true;
                else {
                    open[id] = false;
                    return el.width(previousWidth);
                }
            });
            el.blur(function () {
                open[id] = false;
                return el.width(previousWidth);
            });
            el.change(function () {
                open[id] = false;
                return el.width(previousWidth);
            });
        }
    }
    return this;
};
})(jQuery);
```

Call the function :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mydropdownlist').IELongDropDown();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can not open the select list but you can do it by changing the size of theselect list on click or any other event you want

```
        $("#drpdwn").mousedown(bodyevent);
        function bodyevent()
        {
            console.log("size changed");
            $(this).attr('size',3);
        }
        $("#drpdwn").focus(function()
        {
            //alert("txt  clicked from ");
            var $el = $("#drpdwn");
            var offset = $el.offset();
            var event = jQuery.Event( "mousedown", {
                which: 1,
                pageX: offset.left,
                pageY: offset.top
            });
            $el.trigger(event);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use the [select2](https://select2.org/) plugin and do the following:

```
$(element_select).focus(); 
$(element_select).select2('open').trigger('open');
```

It worked perfectly for me in Firefox version 79.0

Answer (score -1):

There is an  alternate solution i found for this problem. Just add a theme to your select box like Selectize.js it will convert your select box into ul li html tags but works as select box. You can easily hide show ul li's on jquery events.