# How to select an item in dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, casperjs

How to select an item in a dropdown menu so then I can send the form ? Here is the form :

```
<form class="form-inline" method="get" action="http://www.thebonnotgang.com/quotes/q.php">
<input type="hidden" value="1m" name="timeframe">
<input class="span2" type="date" value="2011-07-01" name="dayFrom">
<input class="span2" type="date" name="dayTo">
<select class="span3" name="symbol">
<option>Select...</option>
<option value="VXZ">ETF - iPath MT</option>
<option value="VXX">ETF - iPath ST</option>
<button type="submit"> Download </button>
</select>
</form>
```

[image: Form]

The xPath of the `select` dropdown menu is `/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/ul/li/div/div[2]/form/select`.

I tried `sendKeys` :

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.sendKeys(x('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/ul/li/div/div[2]/form/select'), 'FTSEMIB - Tods');
});
```

but after taking a screenshort the `Select...` option is still selected.

I also tried to click on the `select` element in order to expand the list but I take a screenshot and it doesn't expand anything.
I tried to click directly on the option I want with `casper.thenClick(x('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/ul/li/div/div[2]/form/select/option[3]'));` but after taking a screenshot I still have the `Select...` option selected.

Any idea ?  Also is it possible to send the form without clicks but directly send the formated data ? Also how to learn to use casperjs properly, do you need a solid background in js and webdeveloppment to do these simple tasks easily ?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [*How to automatically expand html select element in javascript*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923600/how-to-automatically-expand-html-select-element-in-javascript). You can make a particular option selected by either setting the select element's [*selectedIndex* property](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-select-selectedindex) to the index of the Option you want selected, or setting the [*selected* property](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-option-selected) of the appropriate option.

Comment: Have you tried it with the various `fill` functions like [`fillSelectors`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fillselectors)?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing "select" tag.

```
<form class="form-inline" method="get" action="http://www.thebonnotgang.com/quotes/q.php">
    <input type="hidden" value="1m" name="timeframe">
    <input class="span2" type="date" value="2011-07-01" name="dayFrom">
    <input class="span2" type="date" name="dayTo">
    <select class="span3" name="symbol">
        <option>Select...</option>
        <option value="VXZ">ETF - iPath MT</option>
        <option value="VXX">ETF - iPath ST</option>
        <button type="submit"> Download </button>
    </select> <!--This right here.-->
</form>
```

I am afraid I cannot answer your question to its entirety, but this should help your syntax.

Comment: I just forgot to copy paste the closing tag from the website

Answer (score 0):

Changing the attribute `selectedIndex` gets the job done (thanks to RobG):

```
casper.then(function () {
    this.evaluate(function () { return document.getElementsByName("symbol")[0].selectedIndex = 14; });
});
```