# make the drop down menu show from another buttons click

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I click on my `a href` button  how do I make the drop down menu show?

```
<a href="#" onclick"makeIDCarsMenuShow()" >my button</a>
<select name="cars" id="cars">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat" selected="selected">Fiat</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>


<script>
  function makeIDCarsMenuShow(){
    $('#cars').trigger('click');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048213/open-select-using-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <a href="#" onclick"return makeIDCarsMenuShow()" >my button</a>
 <select name="cars" id="cars">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="fiat" selected="selected">Fiat</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select>


<script>
   function makeIDCarsMenuShow(){
    $('#cars').click();
    return false;
   }
</script>
```