# Show select dropdown in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due)

Is it possible to make the dropdown on a select element visible with jQuery?

I tried using `$('#dropdown').click();`, but it has no effect.

Comment: maybe focus but I doubt.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800266/programmatically-open-a-drop-down-menu/2800276#2800276

Comment: Cheers, I did try searching, Guess I did not use the right words... Thanks

Comment: Another example: http://jsfiddle.net/mtLUp/4/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible. You can only implement your own select-box, but this is bad for usability.

another approach is to programmatically change the size-attribute of the select-box, but this is not really what you wanted.

I suggest to think of why you need this and if there would be a nicer software-pattern?

Comment: It is possible now - just fireEvent mousedown - solved here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453393/how-to-open-the-select-input-using-jquery

Comment: Only worked in Chrome for me. IE8 or FF didn't work; so it still isn't possible in a browser friendly way.

Answer (score 3):

No - you are unable to do this. It's roughly along the same lines of a button in it's pressed state when a user clicks it - an 'interim' operation for the user to set a value. You could `focus` to it, but that's about it.

If you *really* wanted to simulate this, you could play with some CSS. For example, you could create a list that *looks* like the dropdown list and set the dropdown value based on whatever the user clicks - similar to how an autocomplete list looks.

You could always change it to a multiple line list box if you wanted to display all the values to the user. You'd do this by setting the `size` to any value and back to 1 when you want to hide. It's not perfect, but it's another option:

```
$("#open").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#myselect").attr("size",5);    
});

$("#myselect").click(function(){
   $(this).attr("size",1); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/cr25U/

Answer (score 2):

Here's my adaption:

**HTML**

```
<button id='btn'>Click Me</button>
<select id='test'>
    <option>Blah 1</option>
    <option>Blah 2</option>
    <option>Blah 3</option>
    <option>Blah 4</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#test').attr('size', 5);
});

$('#test').change(function() {
   $(this).attr('size', 1); 
});
```

This doesn't open the drop list, but it kind of works.

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sje397/suNQG/).