# Can I open a selectbox with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show select dropdown in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457076/jquery-show-select-dropdown)

Is it possible to open a selectbox with JavaScript? Or with jQuery?

Comment: Yes it is possible you have to trigger mousedown event by fireEvent

Comment: checkout http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-open

Answer (score 5):

In short: no, it's not possible. Long answer, see *[How do you open a select box with JavaScript?](http://solidlystated.com/scripting/open-select-box-with-javascript/)*.

Comment: Adding this as an option kendo has a dropdown that has an open method  https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#methods-open

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "open" a selectbox, this is impossible - see Stack Overflow question *[Click trigger on select box doesn't work in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895608/jquery-click-trigger-on-select-box-doesnt-work)* for more information.

If you want to select a value, you should use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score -2):

Duplicate: [Show select dropdown in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457076/jquery-show-select-dropdown)

Can't be done, you can use `.trigger('focus')` but it will not open the drop down.