# Is it possible to expand a drop down box dynamically in javascript (its like selecting a dropdown box in html page)

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a drop down box in a `jsp` page like: Select |*_*_|▼|  which having the following values:

1. apple
2. Mango
3. Banana.

Now I call a java script function through a text box onblur event. In that function can
I display that drop down box view like this:

```
Select |_____|▼|
       |apple  |
       |Mango  |
       |Banana |
```

(Instead of clicking the ▼ button can make the view of the drop down box like selecting in jsp)

Comment: What have you tried? Yes, you definitely can. Search for how to write a `select` tag in html.

Comment: Can you please tell me in details or paste same example

Comment: You are asking how to use a select element?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no direct option for that. You will have to simulate a select box.. :(

Comment: Duplicate of [Show select dropdown in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992639/can-i-open-a-selectbox-with-javascript). Explanaition also mentioned inthat question: [How do you open a select box with JavaScript?](http://solidlystated.com/scripting/open-select-box-with-javascript/).

Comment: I suspect opening the drop down on blur of another field is good user experience. If the user blurs that field using the tab key she/he might give the drop down foucs which enables her to navigate the items using the up/down keys. You should of course [order the items' index](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.11) to archieve this. If you need to point the user to that drop down you shoud show a hint next to it. Lastly, if you really want to do this, nunespascal's answer seems OK to me.

Answer (score 1):

Normal selects cannot be expanded in javascript. However you can use a multi-select to achieve this behavior.

Like this:

```
<select id="test" multiple="multiple" size=1
        onFocus="this.size = 3;" 
        onBlur="this.size = 1;">
  <option >apple</option>
  <option >mango</option>
  <option >banana</option>
</select>
```

Take a look at this [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5UGhL/2/).