# How do i open a <select> menu in by pressing enter on keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, marionette

For a  menu in html, clicking on the select will show the drop down with options, but how would I trigger this by clicking on the enter key. I have tried setting up a keyup listener which would then trigger the 'click' event, but the  menu is not showing up

Comment: This is not currently possible unfortunately: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992639/can-i-open-a-selectbox-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Why not try an easier approach? Select opens when you hit enter when it has focus on it, so basically you need only to autofocus when the page load. Example:

```
<select id="dropdown" autofocus class="" name="">
 <option value="">Opt1</option>
 <option value="">Opt2</option>
 <option value="">Opt3</option>
</select>
```

If you still want to trigger the event EVERY time enter is hitted, you can do this:

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 13) {
  document.getElementById("dropdown").focus();
 }
}, false);
```

Basically, select gain focus when you hit enter, then you can hit again to open it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, the  options are opened by using either the up/down arrow keys once the field is in focus. Its something that is build in the html, so no need to create separate listeners for it