# Function that dropdowns list of option in "select" element

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due)
>   [Show select dropdown in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457076/show-select-dropdown-in-jquery)

Suppose i have an select element like this:

```
<div>
<label>Colors</label>
<select class="clients">
 <option selected="selected">All</option>
 <option>Blue</option>
 <option>Green</option>
 <option>Yellow</option>
 <option>Brown</option>
</select>
    <img class="select-arrow" src="images/select-arrow.png" />
</div>
```

i'm very interested in how to dropdown list of option by clicking on the image, for now i've tried

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.select-arrow').click(function(){
        $('.clients').focus();
    })
})
```

but not sucessed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: DON'T delete it.  Deleting questions, if done a lot, can get you question banned.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a select-replacement script to replace all of your standard select boxes with attractive alternatives. You can then add alternative triggers for the drop-down image.

Try something like [uniform](http://uniformjs.com/)