# How to open the select input using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

So I can see the options of the select element but I need to click on it. What if I want to use a function? When something happens this select element should be selected, means the list is open and I can see the options. I don't want the user to click on the select element, I want something else to open it.

**What I've tried**

```
$("select").select();
$("select").click();
$("select").focus();
```

There is a select element, usually if you want it to open (the drop down list), you click on it. What I want is to open it if I click on a `DIV` or anything else. I want this drop down list to to open, without having the user clicking on the select element.

Comment: are you trying to open drop-down when you click on input

Comment: as far as I know you can't force a (native) `<select>` element to just "drop down".

Comment: checkout http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-open

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should work:

```
var element = $("select")[0], worked = false;
if (document.createEvent) { // all browsers
    var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    worked = element.dispatchEvent(e);
} else if (element.fireEvent) { // ie
    worked = element.fireEvent("onmousedown");
}
if (!worked) { // unknown browser / error
    alert("It didn't worked in your browser.");
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FVZkX/)

Comment: I tried the fiddle but how am I supposed to make it open by itself? Should I click somewhere?

Comment: [So where's your problem just do it on whatever event you like.](http://jsfiddle.net/FVZkX/76/)

Comment: It worked on Chrome, don't know why not on Firefox. (It didn't give me the alert)

Comment: ohh.. hmm ask ff devs cause after [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-initMouseEvent) this should work and [ff implemented it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createEvent).

Comment: This worked in Chrome, Safari. Did not work in IE9, IE10, Firefox, Mobile Safari (iPad).

Comment: Perfect. Only added `if ($(element).is(':active')) return;` to not click in the element when it is already opened.

Comment: @Sopo there's actually a more modern way to do this now.

Comment: Can u give reference link

Comment: Thanks for this. Firefox 43 runs the createEvent condition, but doesn't open the menu. Don't know if there's some issue with the initMouseEvent arguments or if Firefox is just not going to play ball at all. :/

Comment: Nice but that won't work anymore very soon: https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5718803933560832

Answer (score 5):

Just an update here as the accepted answer is correct but outdated and `initMouseEvent` is soon to be deprecated. [See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent]

Use the following instead: `new MouseEvent` [See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent]

Example code:

```
var el = $('select'); // grab the input (jQuery)
var event = new MouseEvent('mousedown'); // create the event listener
el.dispatchEvent(event); // attach the event listener to the element
```

Comment: That developer mozilla links are not working anymore.

Comment: you have to select the DOM element var el = $('select')[0], because dispatchEvent() is not a jQuery method. For me this still doesn't work anyways..

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can force the select box to `drop down` using any code. But still you can change the selected option using the code. Pls see this

http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tutorial003.html