# Open <select> below pseudo-element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The HTML as seen in Firebug:

```
<div class="select-contain">
    <select id="sel" name="sel" class="some-class">
    <!-- <option>s -->
    </select>
    ::after
</div>
```

With the CSS :

```
.select-contain:after { background: image.jpg; position: absolute; /** ... */ }
```

The result is something like this:

[image]

The problem is that the image on the `:after` pseudo selector cannot be clicked to open the `<select>`.

I tried doing something with jQuery:

```
jQuery('.select-contain').click(function(e){
    console.log(e); // the event is triggered succesfully
    jQuery(this).find('select').focus(); // .click()
});
```

But this doesn't work due to the fact that I didn't find [a reliable way of opening a `<select>` programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157459/how-to-open-select-element-using-jquery)

Is there any way that I can open the `<select>` with the pseudo element on top of it ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. But if your only purpose is to "style" a dropdown, you might consider using a third-party-plugin (e.g. jquery "chosen", which looks pretty nice i think).

UI generally are known to be unstylable. While you can set border and border-radius to text fields, radio buttons or checkboxes are very limited to css (margin, yay). Good 3rd-party tools have the advantage, that they look equally nice on most browsers.

Comment: @boris: I was afraid of this ... the site is already bloated with javascript, and didn't want to add even more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use css to style them, to a certain extent, but it won't work in all browsers http://caniuse.com/#search=appearance

which is fair enough IMHO as you graceful degrade to a normal select, but of course that needs to be ok with your project

this is a good resource if you'd like to have a look: http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/custom-select-drop-downs-with-css3/

Comment: Thanks for the resources, I'll check them out

Comment: The best I could find was using: `.select-container:after { pointer-events: none; }`. Appears to work on all browsers except IE 8-10 (damn IE)