# In jquery when click on the other element it triggers the dropdown list and the dropdown list has to open

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

In jquery when click the other element that triggers the dropdown list and to show the option .
here is the script code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").on("click",function(){
        alert("ee");
    });
    $("#element").on("click",function(){
        $("select").trigger("click");
    });
});
```

In this code it shows the alert when click the element but the drop down values is not open.

Answer (score 0):

Unless its a custom dropdown, it cannot be opened with a script. The default form controllers does not allow this, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list)

Answer (score 0):

Answer with help of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16157650/1479535).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").on("click",function(){
       alert("ee");
    });
    $("#element").on("click",function(){
      openSelect("select")
    });
});
var openSelect = function(selector){
     var element = $(selector)[0], worked = false;
    if (document.createEvent) { // all browsers
        var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        worked = element.dispatchEvent(e);
    } else if (element.fireEvent) { // ie
        worked = element.fireEvent("onmousedown");
    }
    if (!worked) { // unknown browser / error
        alert("It didn't worked in your browser.");
    }   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<a id="element">asdasd</a>
```