# jquerymobile - open / close select dropdown programmatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to open/close a select dropdown content programmatically, but I can't figure out how to call "open" and "close" on the select

Here's an example: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KYnbP/1/)

**CODE**

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57){
        $("#myselect").click();
        $("#keyOpen").empty().text(e.which);
    }else if(e.which >= 58 && e.which <= 90){
        $("#myselect").trigger("click");
        $("#keyClose").empty().text(e.which);
    }
});
```

if the key pressed is numeric (0-9), it should open, if the key pressed is a char (a-z), the select should close.

this set of char is just an example, I'd like to bind the open/close gesture to a keyboard input.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance, best regards

Comment: It's a bit unclear. You want to open the select with a keypress?

Comment: @KeesSonnema Yes, and after it's open with another keypress, I want to close that select

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453393/how-to-open-the-select-input-using-jquery) might help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look to the [documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-open) of the widget and use:

```
$("#myselect").selectmenu( "open" );
$("#myselect").selectmenu( "close" );
```

Also you have to add `data-native-menu="false"` to your markup as native element will not open.

Working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/knTHZ/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a standard SELECT box, you'll have to create your own select-like box and open that.