# How to focus on an element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following html

```
<div>
   <span>Click me</span>
   <select>
       <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('span').on('click', function () {
   $('select').focus(); 
});
```

What I want to do is when I click on span tag the select menu needed to be focused and dropped down **without changing the structure**. I spent hours to find a solution for this but I couldn't.

http://jsfiddle.net/dqc9nLgk/1/

Comment: Can't see anything wrong yo! working here with your code? http://jsfiddle.net/3pe7zv35/

Comment: I don't think you can initiate the drop down...   to focus use `$(this).next('select').focus();` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/629e32ye/1/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453393/how-to-open-the-select-input-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used input as selector in fiddle. it should be select instead:

```
$('span').on('click', function () {
  $('select').focus(); 
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gg1aqsyd/)**

**Update:** For opening dropdown-

```
var dropdown = $('select')[0];
event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
dropdown.dispatchEvent(event);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/31vxt5mb/)**

Comment: Ah... but i need select menu to be dropped down as well

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible to change markup, you may use [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) html element instead of span. It is been designed to do what you want (or describing here) without JavaScript.

**UPD:**

About "dropped down" `select`, I suggest you to read related question: [How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span').on('click', function () {
   $('select').focus(); 
});


http://jsfiddle.net/dqc9nLgk/2/
```