# HmmerJS - make mousedown consistent on browser and touch devices

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, touch, hammer.js

I'm using HammerJS to handle gestures. I have a `div` element (which hammer is managing events on) that contains a `select` within. In touch devices, or on `device mode` of the chrome development tools, I am able to open the select by just tapping and also moving the whole `div` by touching and panning, I can drag the whole thing even holding the `select` element. (this is my intended behavior).

On the other hand, when using a mouse. As soon as I click on the `select`, it opens. So, I'm not able to drag the element around.

In both devices, it seems the event reaches Hammer by bubbling, since it is waiting for them on the containing `div`. But the difference seems to be that *clicking (tapping?) and dragging* on touch device doesn't fire the *mousedown* event, only tapping does.

*Would it be possible to have the browser behave like the touch device does, allowing me to drag my `div` by holding the `select` and still being able to have it unfold on click?*

*Is there any information on the event that could help differentiate between the two?*

Am I looking at it sideways? I'm new to HammerJS.

**What have I tried?**

Listening for the *mousedown* event on the `select`, preventing the default behavior, letting the event bubble and trying to imperatively open the `select` on the tap event (eventmanager). But it seems one simply can not, at least, <strike>the approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453393/how-to-open-the-select-input-using-jquery) didn't work.</strike>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired consistency by conditionally preventing the default behavior on the `mousedown` event, and letting it bubble up to the hammerJS Tap handler.

```
var someCondition = false;

function preventDefaultWithCondition (ev) {
    if (someCondition) {
        someCondition = false;
        ev.stopPropagation();
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise prevent the default behavior
    ev.preventDefault();
    this.blur();
    window.focus();
}
```

Then on the Tap event handler:

```
function onTap (ev) {
   if (ev.target.tagName === 'SELECT') {
      someCondition = true;
      /* Trigger the mousedown event programmatically on the select. */
   }
}
```

The technique I used to trigger the `mousedown` event is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453393/how-to-open-the-select-input-using-jquery?lq=1)

The general idea is that the ultimate decision to whether open or not the select is ultimately delegated to HammerJS regardless of device.