# how to fire mouse down event in firefox using javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I want to trigger mouse down event of combo box/selection box using javascript. here is the code, it is working perfect in crome but not in Firefox. any help on this ??

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
<br>
<button id="fire" type="button" onclick="runThis()">Show dropdown items</button>

// <select> element displays its options on mousedown, not click.
showDropdown = function (element) {
    var event;
    event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    //event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
    event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
};

// This isn't magic.
window.runThis = function () {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
    showDropdown(dropdown);
};
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: is `element.click()` good enough?

Comment: @H2CO3 - no, what i want is, when user click some option in drop down then it loads the data in this and select that option but i want to keep that drop down open.. 

compare this in crome and FF and see the difference :

http://jsfiddle.net/fz2sY/106/

Comment: I am having the same issue and can't find out anything! Since when doesn't `mousedown` work at all in Firefox??

Answer (score 0):

It just seems that this in not possible. See similar questions:

- [How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due)
- [Show select dropdown in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457076/show-select-dropdown-in-jquery)
- [Click trigger on select box doesn't work in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895608/click-trigger-on-select-box-doesnt-work-in-jquery)