# Auto Open select box options on page load jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-selectbox

On jquery mobile, how can I auto open the select box when page loads? Like in this sample:
[image: open select box on page load]

My code:

```html
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <select name="select-choice-usa" id="select-choice-usa" size="15">
                <option>USA</option>
                <option selected="selected">EUROPE</option>
                <option>UK</option>
            </select>

            <select name="select-choice-size" id="select-choice-size">
                <option selected="selected">3.5</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>4.5</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

The script I tried:

```css
$('#page1').live("pagecreate", function() {
    $('#select-choice-usa').attr('parent',focus())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, it can't be done: [Show select dropdown in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457076/show-select-dropdown-in-jquery).

You can implement your own selectbox but that's about it.