# Blur is not working for select menu on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want blur select menu when it is open. I have made a small function when you hover the mouse  on a tag then blur function will call. It is working fine in other browser but not working in Chrome. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xMYQa/)

Reproduce bug : click and open select menu and hover anchor tag, open select menu should be closed

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   $('a').hover(function(){
    $('select').blur();
   })
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select>
<option>Test</option>
<option>Test</option>
<option>Test</option>
<option>Test</option>
<option>Test</option>
<option>Test</option>
<option>Test</option>
</select>
<a href="#">hover me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851882/close-a-select-dropdown-list-programatically-with-javascript-jquery - the second answer here seems to deal with the chrome issue

Comment: @amit .. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with `.blur()` ?

Comment: put focus on it first

Comment: its a behaviour of chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, and the idea was clear: you cannot blur an opened select element, because Chrome and Safari waits for the answer. BUT there is a workaround that you may find acceptable.

First, you cannot set focus to another element while the "select" is still active, so I have removed it by applying a "display:none".
After that I trigger a click event on another harmless element.
And then I re-add the select back, by setting a display:block.
In this case, the code would look like(i will add a span to click on):

```
.......
<select>
<option>Test</option>
......
</select>
<a href="#">hover me</a>
<span class="clickable">element clicked</span>
.......
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
    jQuery("a").mouseenter(function (){
        $("select").css({'display':'none'});
        $("span.clickable").focus().click();
        $("select").css({'display':'block'});
    });    
});
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't it affect accessibility to drop the focus into a random element? It seems like you're stranding users who tab through elements. 

Is there an accessibility-friendly solution available?

Comment: This did the trick. `$("select").blur()` worked in IE, Edge, and Chrome - but not Firefox. `$("select").css({ "display": "none" }).blur().css({ "display": "inline" });` did the trick across all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use  [**.trigger()**](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) for that

```
<select id="selectboxId">
.......
</select>

   $ ('#selectboxId').trigger('blur');
```

Comment: I didn't downvote.. but..  `.blur()` is shortcut for `.trigger('blur')` see the api `-->` http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: no when we want to fire blur event with out doing that manually we will use trigger

Comment: It is behaving like blur event. bug still there

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/blur/  When `blur()` is called without any arguments, this method is a shortcut for `.trigger('blur')`.