# force safari iOS select component to update when options change

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, mobile-safari

When you tap on a select input on a web page using iOS (iPhone), a spinner widget (the "picker") pops up and lets you spin through and select options within that select. Let's say you've tapped into one of these and the selector widget is open. While this is open, if you use javascript to modify the select options (add, remove, update options via the dom), then these changes don't get reflected in the widget unless the user closes and reopens the widget.

Is there a way to force the browser to update the options automatically?

[image]

Edit: Here is an example you can use to observe how updating select options doesn't update the selector widget: http://jsfiddle.net/RrsNk/

```
<select id="my-select" />

$(function () {
    updateSelect();
});

function updateSelect() {
    $("#my-select").empty();
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var ran = Math.random();
        $("<option />").attr("value", ran).html(ran).appendTo("#my-select");
    }
    setTimeout(updateSelect, 2000);
}
```

Comment: no, the IOS select works in the same modal-ish way that prompt() and confirm() do...

Comment: cars.com does it somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari uses a `UIPickerView` to display the dropdown menus. As you would expect, the title of the dropdown component in the page is updated according to the changes in the DOM but the picker view is not tightly coupled with the DOM so it isn't updated. The situation is the same with Chrome and Opera Mini.

So in conclusion, **it is not possible what you are trying to implement**. You should look for other ways to make your dataset accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I was brought to this question as the closest to my usage case, which is similar but not identical, and might apply to other people as it is a common situation.  I found the answers here a touch confusing, so just wanted to clarify my findings.

1. I start with a dropdown containing just one `option`: `Searching...`.
2. When the user clicks, the "picker" pops up (a "tick-list" on iPad, same principle as the "spinner" on iPhone), showing `Searching...`.
3. An AJAX call gets come choices from the server, and JavaScript updates the `options[]` to these.
4. At this point, the picker still shows just `Searching...`, and the user has no clue that it has been repopulated. The user must click outside to dismiss the "picker", and click the dropdown again to see the new choices.

So in my case I do not have OP's situation of wanting a second dropdown to be displayed depending on what option is selected in the first dropdown.  Rather I would like (#1) the "picker" disappear, and then (#2) reappear (with the new choices).

Now, it seems you *can* do #1, but *not* #2.

1. You *can* dismiss the "picker" by `dropdown.blur()` (tested in Mobile Safari).  See [Close a SELECT dropdown list programatically with Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851882/close-a-select-dropdown-list-programatically-with-javascript-jquery).
2. You *cannot* cause the "picker" to pop up again (at least not in Mobile Safari).  See [How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due).

So I am at least doing #1, so that the user gets some feedback rather than just being stuck with `Searching...`.

If anyone can state how you can do #2 on Mobile Safari I would be very interested to hear....

Answer (score 0):

Worth trying: populate a second `<select>` element, and `.focus()` to it when the item in the first select list is chosen.

Note that iOS only allows a control to be focused within a user interactive events (touchend or click event) so I am guessing Safari Mobile might allow `.focus()` to work within a `<select>` (to opening the second select list).

Might not work, since an `onchange` event of a select list might not be deemed "interactive" or Safari Mobile might otherwise disallow `selectElement.focus()` to work for some reason.

Edit: I think this shows it is unlikely to work: [force safari iOS select component to update when options change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339021/force-safari-ios-select-component-to-update-when-options-change/58002830#58002830)

Don't bother trying if you need to contact a server to fill the list. That is because when you get the response event, you are definitely not in a user interactive tap/click event handler, so `.focus()` is sure to be ignored (although there is a very slight chance an async chain could work).

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, why would you want to - you should adjust the values in your HTML file, or with JavaScript as the page is loading.

However, if the values are changing as the user selects the dropdown, you can use JavaScript to select another element, then reselect the dropdown, causing it to reload.

You can bring focus to an element with the focus() method. Eg.
    Document.getElementById("input").focus();

Comment: Unfortunately .focus() does not trigger the picker to open on iOS. The user would have to tap the select element again.

Comment: As to why you would do this - think cascading ajax dropdowns. The content of the second dropdown gets loaded in dynamically once the user selects something from the first dropdown. I have a large data set, so it has to work this way. What's happening is that the user is hitting "next" to go to the second dropdown before the content is loaded from the server. When the content is finally ready to the load, then user already has the picker up which needs to have its values updated.

Comment: @Rafe I don't know if this achievable or not, but it's defintely confusing to user experience. I'd recommend that you have the 2nd select disabled, when user select an option from the 1st list, display a loading label near the 2nd list, enable it when Ajax request is complete