# How to close dropdown on onchange event of selector In iOS6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on hybrid application with worklight.

When tapping on select control, a native dropdown pops out. Now I have bound onchange event on this select so when I choose any option the event gets fired but the dropdown doesn't fadeout until I tap on the done button.

I have used `('select').blur()` to overcome and it is working fine for Android but not for iOS6.

I want to fadeout the dropdown with onchange.

Code:

```
<select id="myID" onchange="myFun()">;

function myFun(){
    $('select').blur();
}

or

function myFun(){
    $('#myID').blur();
}
```

What are the possible soultions for it? Thanks.

Comment: Parth, if my answer below helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.

Comment: I didn't check it, I will check it, then sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While my previous answer will work, only in iOS6, the following works for me in both iOS6 and iOS7 using the [iOS7-Select-Element-Auto-Close plug-in by lukewhyte](https://github.com/lukewhyte/iOS7-Select-Element-Auto-Close).

Simply place the JS code provided in the plug-in in your project and include it in your index.html,

```
<script src="js/select.js"></script>
```

Then:

**HTML**

```
<div id="mySelectDiv">
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    $('#mySelect').iOSSelect();
    $("#mySelect").bind('change', changeValue);
}

function changeValue() {
    $("#selectedOption").val($("#mySelect option:selected").text());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that in iOS you cannot use `.blur()` on a `select` element, the event will be ignored.

*Note: in iOS the user is **expected** to tap the Done button. Why confuse your end-user by introducing **unexpected** interaction and behavior (= not provided by the OS to begin with). For example, what if the user selected by mistake? Instead of being able to correct on the spot, s/he will be forced to tap again and select again... I recommend leaving it with the default behavior.*

*Updated example: instead of removing the `select` from the DOM and re-introducing it, [I've found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851882/close-a-select-dropdown-list-programatically-with-javascript-jquery).

[The below works only in iOS6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wR0Wk.gif), though, per the question. It doesn't work in iOS7.*

**HTML**

```
<div id="mySelectDiv">
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
</div>

Selected option: <input type="text" id="selectedOption"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    $("#mySelect").bind('change', changeValue);
}

function changeValue() {
    var mySelectedIndex = $("#mySelect option:selected").index();

    $("#selectedOption").val($("#mySelect option:selected").text());
    if($("#mySelect").is("select")){
        var fakeSelect = $("#mySelect").clone();
        $("#mySelect").replaceWith(fakeSelect);
        $("#mySelect").bind('change', changeValue);
        $("#mySelect").prop('selectedIndex', mySelectedIndex);
    }
}
```