# Close the select option window on Div hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Need a quick help. I like to close the option drop down when you hover the other div element.

So first open the drop down and hover the red element on right side, while hover over red element i want to close the drop down.

Thanks in advance.

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>

<div></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Close a SELECT dropdown list programmatically with Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851882/close-a-select-dropdown-list-programmatically-with-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On div hover, you can simply trigger `blur()` event on the select element like:

**Using `mouseenter`:**

```js
let myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv"); 
let mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect"); 
myDiv.addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {   
  mySelect.blur();
}, false);
```

```css
select{width:200px;display:inline-block}
#myDiv{width:50px;height:50px;background:red;display:inline-block}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

**Using `onmouseover`:**

```js
let myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
let mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");
myDiv.onmouseover = function() {
  mySelect.blur();
};
```

```css
select{width:200px;display:inline-block}
#myDiv{width:50px;height:50px;background:red;display:inline-block}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

**Using jQuery [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/):**

```js
$('#myDiv').hover(function() {
  $('#mySelect').blur();
});
```

```css
select{width:200px;display:inline-block}
#myDiv{width:50px;height:50px;background:red;display:inline-block}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: I'm on Chromium Linux, the mousenter doesn't work on your fiddle ...., but well on firefox

Comment: @BENARDPatrick: Try once using `onmouseover` I have added a demo for it.

Comment: @palaѕн This is exactly i need. Thanks Man.

Comment: I think it's an issue on Chromium Linux, none of the fiddle works, I tried too on Chrome, not works... But as I said works fine on Firefox. I don't know why... Your answer is the good I know. Just to say : Chrome with Ubuntu with Kde Flavour, not works...