# chosen jquery plugin: how to automatically drop the next dropdown after selecting from previous dropdown?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I have [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201098/how-to-automatically-drop-the-next-dropdown-after-selecting-from-previous-dropdo) about automatically dropping the next dropdown after selecting from previous dropdown, but now I'm trying to work it out with [chosen jquery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

The solution there is not working if Chosen is plugged in.

I tried fiddling something like this:

```
$("select").chosen().each(function () {
    $("#select1").on("chosen:hiding_dropdown", function () {

        var $chzn   = $('#select2').next()

        $chzn.find(".chosen-drop").show();

    });
});
```

But it's not working.. even with slidedown. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/betteful/rt97wtqc/8/)

Comment: question: is the markup that you are currently working with the same as the html markup in the previous question? the only difference is that you are using the chosen plugin?

Comment: @kryptonkal yes, same mark up, no changes.

Comment: have you tried using the built-in chosen events? chosen:hiding_dropdown? change? You could open up the next dropdown on the chosen change event.

Comment: tried something like this just now: http://jsfiddle.net/betteful/rt97wtqc/8/
not working..

Comment: you could try $('#select_id').trigger('chosen:open');