# Trigger a select form element to show its options (open drop down options list) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Here is the markup

```
<select id="person_prefix" name="prefix">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="Dr" selected="selected">Dr</option>
 <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
 <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
 <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
</select>
```

and I want to trigger a javascript event so that the option list drops down. Using jquery I've tried the following:

```
$("#person_prefix").click();
$("#person_prefix").mousedown();
$("#person_prefix").change();
```

but nothing seems to work. Which event is this and how can be triggered?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due)

Comment: ^ Asim's answer specifically. Disappointing :(

Answer (score 8):

I was once searching how to do the same thing and didn't find any working solution but then a guy in our javascript group came with a clever work around. Here is the code.

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="show" value="show" />
<select id="myslect">
    <option>nothing</option>
    <option>something</option>
    <option>anything</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#show").click(function () {
    var element = $("select")[0],
        worked = false;
    if(document.createEvent) { // chrome and safari
        var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        worked = element.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
    if(!worked) { // unknown browser / error
        alert("It didn't worked in your browser.");
    }
});
```

I'm not sure how to link to the group post so you can see the whole thread. Anyway credits to CJ Madolara. Good Job!

**Update:** *Only works on Chrome and Safari*

Comment: Hey your solution is working for me but the select options disappear at the end of the click. How would you do it to keep the select options displayed until one is actually selected ?

Comment: These days this only works in Safari (still doesn't work in Firefox and no longer works in Chrome).

Comment: [if you're looking for an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39635285/2518317), @derpedy-doo

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this cross-browser programmatically.  You can *replace* the dropdown with an entirely custom solution not actually *displaying* a `<select>` element...but you can't programmatically show it, especially in IE.

The *closest* you can do is move the user to the element via [`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/):

```
$("#person_prefix").focus();
```

This with some CSS styling for when it's focused (`:focus`) is usually a pretty good way to draw attention to it.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the **size** attribute the select will display the number of options you specify in size.

```
var sel= document.getElementsByName('select_1')[0];
var len= '10'// or sel.options.length;
// safest: var len=sel.getElementsByTagName('*').length;
sel.setAttribute('size',len)
```

Setting size back to '1' collapses the select.

Comment: Some browsers don't account for optgroups, others count them like options and so don't show 10 options if you have 2 optgroups and specify options.length or 10.

Comment: Sorry, I stuttered and echoed my own comment.

Answer (score 2):

You **can't** trigger click event on select form element but the proper workaround is this plugin:
[jQuery.customSelect](http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/)

The great advantage is that it launches the real `select` element (you actually click on an invisible select - `opacity: 0`), which is important on mobile devices (e.g. iPhone has its own layout for displaying `select's` options).

If you don't want to download the whole plugin you can then prepare the solution on your own since you know how to trigger the `select` (hide it by setting `opacity: 0` - it will be still clickable).

Answer (score 0):

building on @kennebec's answer, a jQuery version to get a count of the options and optgroups:

```
var sel = $('select.mySelectClass'); 
var count=0;

sel.find('option').each(function() {

     count++;
});

sel.find('optgroups').each(function() {

     count++;
});

sel.attr('size',count);
```

Comment: `var count = sel.find('option, optgroups').length;`

Answer (score 0):

initMouseEvent is deprecated now, use this instead:

```
let e = new MouseEvent('mousedown', {
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true,
  view: window
})
element.dispatchEvent(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTMLSelectElement.showPicker()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/showPicker) method e.g.

```
document.getElementById('person_prefix').showPicker();
```

At time of writing this is supported in most latest browser versions, but disabled behind a feature flag in Safari.