# Make a label related to a select element clickable

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to click on the label related to the select element and make it drop down as it would normally do if you clicked on the select element itself?

I have tried this and it doesn't work:

```
        <li>
            <div class="styled-select">
                <label for="lang">Languages</label>
                <select id="lang">
                    <option class="green">eng</option>
                    <option class="green">fr</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </li>
```

The reason why I am asking this is that the label will be floated left and the select right.

Comment: It's not possible AFAIK. `Select` is handled by the user exclusively in that case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger a select form element to show its options (open drop down options list) with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846735/trigger-a-select-form-element-to-show-its-options-open-drop-down-options-list)

Comment: possible duplicate of [click-trigger-on-select-box-doesnt-work-in-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895608/click-trigger-on-select-box-doesnt-work-in-jquery)

Comment: also more similar info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622191/trigger-click-on-select-box-on-hover)

Comment: Thanks for the info, however they didnt help for this specific case. I will rethink about another solution.

Comment: Another solution is to mimick with JS a custom  dropdown box styled with CSS. On click simply pass the value to the original hidden select element.