# HTML5 input date type jQuery trigger

Tags: jquery, html, input

I'm trying to programmatically trigger the *dropdown* component (the calendar bit) of an input of type date (similar to clicking the down arrow on the input field). Is this possible? I don't want to use a datepicker library.

HTML:

```
<input type="date" id="myDatePicker">
<button id="myButton">Click Me</button>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    //$('#myDatePicker').click();//Doesn't do anything...
    //$('#myDatePicker').blur();//Doesn't do anything...
    //$('#myDatePicker').change();//Doesn't do anything...
    //$('#myDatePicker').focus();//Doesn't do anything...
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/joepegler/mvobkjcu/8/

Comment: Related: [Trigger a select form element to show its options (open drop down options list) with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846735/trigger-a-select-form-element-to-show-its-options-open-drop-down-options-list)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mvobkjcu/13/

Comment: Basically according to that question you are not going to be able to achieve this without some plugin or complex workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short it would appear that you can't. I used a datepicker instead.

Answer (score 2):

**2022 Update**

You can use [showPicker()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/showPicker)

IE:

```
$('#myDatePicker').showPicker()
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this out, (achieved this using plugin)

http://jsfiddle.net/pandiyancool/v6zpbmao/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#myDatePicker").datepicker({
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonText: 'Click me',
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                constrainInput: true
            });

            $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").mouseover(function() {
                $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
            });

        });
```

Comment: Per the OP: _"I don't want to use a datepicker library..."_