# javascript to pull down select menu programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to use javascript or jquery to automatically pull down a select menu drop down, upon click of a button. I'm having this issue since I'm using a text field which allows for custom user input to add a field dynamically to a select input, and I don't want the user to click twice, but essentially the problem is this:

```js
$("#dropDownButton").click(function(){
  //$("#selectBox"). //What goes here???

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selectBox">
  <option val=1>1</option>
  <option val=2>2</option>
</select>

<button id="dropDownButton">
  Pull Down The Select!
</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846735/trigger-a-select-form-element-to-show-its-options-open-drop-down-options-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There possibly **NO** way to do this directly but there several weys instead.
Like

:: Using a Label for Select and trigger a click event on it.

:: Use `.focus()` for focusing to the select element.

:: And one of the best is to make a select

```
$('#dropDownButton').click(function() {
        var length = $('#selectBox option').length;
       //open dropdown
        $("#selectBox").prop('size', length);

       // to close

        //$("#selectBox").prop('size', 0);
    });
```

But all of then an alternative to performing the action.There also the best alternative to doing this with a set of another element like `list` and `div` which used by most of the CSS frameworks like Bootstrap and Foundation.

[Bootstrap dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu&stacked=h)

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430237/is-it-possible-to-use-js-to-open-an-html-select-to-show-its-option-list)

Answer (score 1):

On button click , check whether the select box size is 1 or more. If it is 0 or 1 then , make it the max size on button click like this.

```
        $("#dropDownButton").click(function(){
        //$("#selectBox"). //What goes here???

        var no = document.getElementById("selectBox").length;
        var s;

        if($("#selectBox").prop('size') == 0 || $("#selectBox").prop('size') == 1 ) {
            s = no;    
        }
        else {
            s = 1;
        }
        $("#selectBox").attr('size', s);
    });
```