# Programmatically open <select> picker

Tags: javascript, android, html, webkit

I would like to programmatically open the picker for the select element below.

```
<select id="select1" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="MDO1" selected="selected">MDO 1</option>
  <option value="MDO2">MDO 2</option>
  <option value="MDO3">MDO 3</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to do this on Android inside a WebView.  I have tried creating and dispatching `touchstart` and `touchend` events to the `select` like this

```
      var select1 = document.getElementById("select1");
      var evt = document.createEvent('TouchEvent');
      evt.initUIEvent('touchstart', true, true);
      select1.dispatchEvent(evt);
      var evt2 = document.createEvent('TouchEvent');
      evt2.initUIEvent('touchend', true, true);
      select1.dispatchEvent(evt2);
```

but that didn't do anything.  What type of event do I need to fire to get the picker popup to show up?

Comment: Refer the link that could help you get your results, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due

Comment: Refer the link, this might help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due

Answer (score 0):

can you please try with

```
var select1 = document.getElementById("select1");
var evt = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
evt.initUIEvent("click", true, true, window, 1);
select1.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Thanks,
Pushkar