# Open selectBox element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Can you help me? I want to open a selectbox with JS. But it does not work in Firefox. Do not know anyone help me how to solve?

```
<select id="selId" class="pos_fixed">
 <option value="volvo">Option1</option>
 <option value="saab">Option2</option>
 <option value="mercedes">Option3</option>
 <option value="audi">Option4</option>
 </select>
<span class ="xxx">open</span>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".xxx").on('click', function () {
        openSelect($('#selId'));
    });


    var openSelect = function(selector){
        var element = selector[0], worked = false;
        if (document.createEvent) { // all browsers
            var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            worked = element.dispatchEvent(e);
        } else if (element.fireEvent) { // ie
            worked = element.fireEvent("onmousedown");
        }
        if (!worked) { // unknown browser / error
            alert("It didn't worked in your browser.");
        }
    }

});
```

DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/uhYxf/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due)

Answer (score 0):

You will have a hard time to perform this cross-browser. I would opt for using a select box plugin like [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) or [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) instead of using an html `<select>` element.

However, another option which would be easier is to change the `size` property of the select for someting greater than 1 when clicked. That doesn't give the same feel, but could probably fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you,
but Select2 or Chosen generates div element, but I need SelectBox element. There is no other way?

Comment: @user2219071, Could you explain why you specificly need a `<select>` element? There is no way to programmatically expand a select element in all browsers unfortunately, so you will have to use one of the alternatives I suggested.