# How to make select element drop down?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Say I have a simple select element looking like this:

```
<select onfocus="somefunction()">
    <option>Monday</option>
    <option>Tuesday</option>
    <option>Wednesday</option>
</select>
```

How would I create "somefunction()" such that it makes the select form element drop down, as if I had clicked on it?

Comment: You can't do that with the standard form controls.  You would need to use a JS/CSS drop down.

Comment: are you looking for programatically trigger the click event? If yes the comment above has the solution.

Comment: I think this might help [How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due

Answer (score 1):

I know you didn't ask about jquery but how about using select2 instead?
http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: This answer doesn't solve his problem.