# Open a select drop down on click of checkbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a drop down say

```
<select id="countries">
<option value="1">Country</option>
</select>
```

and a check box,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="search_engine" id="search_engine" class="hear" value="search_engine" />
<input type="checkbox" name="search_engine1" id="search_engine1" class="hear" value="search_engine1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="search_engine2" id="search_engine2" class="hear" value="search_engine2" />
```

On the click of the checkbox I want to open the drop down, how can I do that using jquery.

Tried the below code but its not working, I am using jquery 1.10.3

```
function open_drop_down()
{
   $('#countries').show().focus().click();
}
```

Comment: An ID can only be used once per page. [IDs must be unique.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Comment: ok I shall update my code but I have tried focus it does not work either.

Comment: Updated the question now I have my id's different but the point is that  `focus()` does not work!

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 no it doesnot work check my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fakhruddin/bXv9N/

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 as i said it just sets focus but doesnot open the dropdown

Comment: Same questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: From mithunsatheesh's answer, I have integrated the `doClick` function here:

```
var doClick = function() {
    'use strict';
    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
    return event;
};

$('.hear').click(function() {
    'use strict';
    $('#countries').focus().get(0).dispatchEvent(doClick());
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bXv9N/1/). Please note that it only works in Chrome (WebKit).

Also, you may wish to bind to the `change` event.

Comment: I am using class instead of ID but still `focus();` does not work. It just sets the focus and not expand the dropdown.

Comment: getting an error `Cannot call method 'dispatchEvent' of undefined `