# On select change open up the next select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, triggers

I have a few consecutive select elements where the user must chose an option. What I am trying to do for user convenience and to make sure they chose an option is automatically open the next select after an option has been picked

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zYUfd/1/

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <select name="first">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
    </select> 
    <select name="two">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
    </select> 
    <select name="three">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
    </select> 
</form>
```

**jquery**

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
   $('.select').next().trigger('click'); 
});
```

Comment: In short, you can't. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due

Comment: Did you try using $(this).next() instead of $('.select').next()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/4cgt3/ and this http://jsfiddle.net/4cgt3/3/

Old SO reference: [Open a select drop down on click of checkbox using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950376/open-a-select-drop-down-on-click-of-checkbox-using-jquery)

Hope this fits your needs `:)`

**code**

```
$('select').on('change', function () {

    'use strict';
       $(this).next().focus().get(0).dispatchEvent(doClick());

});

var doClick = function () {
    'use strict';
    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
    return event;
}
```

Comment: so much for this being impossible, this almost works perfectly but every drop goes to the second menu, (after selecting the second option it does not move to the third). But this may be enough for me to play around with. thanks

Comment: saweet, fixed, much smoother version here:     http://jsfiddle.net/4cgt3/3/ `:)` Glad it helped!

Comment: boom there it is, you are a genius my man only quitters say something is impossible

Comment: This doesn't work in Firefox, just a heads up. Still a nice enhancement for people using Chrome, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. You would need to use a custom select widget to accomplish this **cross browser**.

Comment: its ok that its not cross browser, its not an essential function but it makes it easier for the user so ill take it on whatever browser it will work on

Comment: Consistency is nice, however.