# How to simulate click on dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is [Google registration page](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp). There is a dropdown list. How to simulate click on it using jQuery? My code doesn't work.

```
$('#Gender').click()
```

[image]

**P.S.**  I am wiritng userscript for another google website and there are same dropdowns. So I don't want to make a script for autoregistration, don't worry.

Comment: Why you want to simulate a click?

Comment: @wumm I just mentioned reason in P.S. I am writing userscript for Google Map Maker

Comment: @wumm Yes, I expect to change value after click. Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Yes it is. Inspect this "select" because it isn't a real select. On the registration page there is an hidden input with the id HiddenGender. To change the value use something like `$("#HiddenGender").val("Male");`

Comment: @wumm did you try that? It doesn't work for me. At least after pasting to Chrome's Webconsole. Anything happens.

Answer (score 0):

try `$('#Gender').trigger("click");`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with HTML + javascript, but it works only on Chrome.

Check [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10136523/1806873).

Answer (score 0):

By looking your screenshot it appear that it is not a real dropdown (i.e. select tag) .

I believe your are using kendodropdown or jquery UI combobox or etc .

it change the dropdown to span,textbox combination and also change the id. 
To fire click event first inspect the element ,then bind it using the actual generated id or you can use class to bind the event .

if this doesn't help you provide  html and javascript .

Comment: You can check the [Google registration page](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp) for the html and javascript