# Open a Select menu, clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Here is the issue, which one I am not able solve. In my page, I am having a select menu. Beside the select menu, one button. What I want is, when I click the button, the select menu will open. Here is the code which one I started.

```
$('#myButton').click(function () {

    $('#mySelect').bind('mousedown', function () {
        console.log('foo');
    });

    $('#mySelect').trigger('mousedown');
});
```

Here is the jsbin link. http://jsbin.com/Odeyocof/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: the answer is...
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due)

Answer (score 0):

There is no default method to open a **select** element in **JavaScript**. But There is a different way to accomplish this task :

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
 $('#mySelect').show();
 $('#mySelect')[0].size=2;/* Choose a size that's perfect */
});
/* Hide Select Menu when user clicks an option */
$('#mySelect').live("click",function(){
 $('#mySelect').hide();
});
```

[Source](http://subinsb.com/2013/11/how-to-open-a-select-element-using-jquery)