# How to open select programmatically

Tags: angularjs, select, triggers

Does anyone know if it is possible to open a select programmatically in angularjs. Ive tried

```
angular.element(el).trigger('focus');
angular.element(el).trigger('click');
angular.element(el).trigger('mousedown');
```

Nothing works.

I also tried

```
$scope.doSomething = function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        var el = document.getElementById('test');
        var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        worked = el.dispatchEvent(e);
    }, 0);

}
```

The above set focus but do not open the select.

Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due

Comment: thanks, i tried it but it doesn't work in angularjs. I updated my question

Comment: sorry, my mistake. It was the timeout that caused the problem. Thanks

Comment: pretty nice, is there a way to do this in IE? It currently doesn't work for me in IE

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73755107/11322237

Answer (score 1):

Try this for Hover:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#selectId").hover(function(){
   $(this)[0].size=$(this).find("option").length;
});
$("#selectId").click(function(){
   $(this)[0].size=0;
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="selectId">
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option >Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting the size of the select and having it float using position:absolute.

```
<div  style="position:relative">.<select style="position:absolute;top:-8px;left:-20px" onClick="onAssign(this)">   
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select></div>

function openMySelect(){
  document.querySelector(‘#mySelect’),size=YOUR_OPTIONS.length;
}

function onAssign(data,select){
  select.size=1
  // your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution, at least works for me:

First, try to get the arrow of the `ng-select` and then force a `mousedown` event

```
let arrowSpan = document.querySelector('.ng-arrow-wrapper');
arrowSpan.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('mousedown', { bubbles: true }))
```

[Select span arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV2cK.png)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```js
function openSelect(selectId) {
    var event = new MouseEvent('mousedown', {
        'view': window,
        'bubbles': true,
        'cancelable': true
    });
    var cb = document.getElementById(selectId);
    cb.size=4;
    cb.dispatchEvent(event);
}
openSelect("testId");
```

or read more here [Triggering built-in events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Firefox, only on Chrome. What is the issue?

Comment: Dear Karel, I test it on Firefox, it work.
May be javascript error?

Answer (score -1):

The answer provided by [haste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36798023/3354175) doesn't work:

```
var cb = element[0].getElementsByClassName('some-selector')[0];
var event = new MouseEvent('mousedown', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
});                        
cb.dispatchEvent(event);
```

I use more simple method:

```
var cb = element[0].getElementsByClassName('some-selector')[0];
angular.element(cb).triggerHandler('click');
```

Comment: your answer is not working either(i.e. the select menu is not opened). tested in Chrome 65

Answer (score -8):

i had same problem and finally i'm create my own directive:

```
angular.module('openselect', [])
    .directive('openselect', function () {
        var showDropdown = function (element) {
            var event;
            event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
            element.dispatchEvent(event);
        };
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                'elemento': '@'
            },
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                elem.bind('click', function () {
                    var elemento = document.getElementById(scope.elemento);
                    showDropdown(elemento);
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

To use:

```
<div style="position:relative">
<span ng-show="submittedForm.contry.$error.required && co_form.contry.$error.required" class="label label-danger">Indicanos tu país</span>
<select name="country" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="formCheckout.country" id="myCountry" placeholder="España" required>
    <option value="6" selected="selected">España</option>
    <option value="1">Alemania</option>
    <option value="15">Portugal</option>
</select>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" style="position: absolute; right: 10px; color: #A6A6A6; top: 18px;" openselect elemento="myCountry"></span>
```

Adds directive to any tag passing id of select (elemento) that you want to open.

You can see the very basic javscript code inside directive if you want to use in other context;

hope it helps ;D

Comment: its dishonorable to copy someone elses genius solution, parrot it as your own and not give them any credit.

Comment: This is a complete disgrace.