# How can i trigger a selectbox click inside a scope function?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am working on phonegap.jquery mobile,Angularjs mobile app

I want to triger a click once ihave clicked in some other icon. for that i am calling to a scope function, from their i have tried with $('#id').click(); But it is not working for me.

```
<div id="clickforsele" ng-click="selectdisplay()">
```

selectbox is
`<select id="seleid"><options.......  </select>`

and the scope function is `$scope.selectdisplay = function () {
$('#seleid').click();
}`

it comes to scope function. But from thei i can not trigger the click. some one could help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What is your goal precisely ? To open the select element ? to select an item ?

If you need to select an item : just use ng-options directive https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

In your html

```
<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

In your controller :

```
$scope.selected = null;// initialize this is important you may have trouble if you forget this
$scope.items = []; // same better to init them as empty array 1st if your doing an asynchrnous request to load them after 
$scope.selectdisplay = function () { $scope.selected = $scope.items[1]}// set the second element as selected.
```

Now if you want to just open the select box i suggest you to check this post [How to open select programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609105/how-to-open-select-programmatically)