# Open select from ts (angular, ng-select)

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I have several ng-selects on a page, and am trying to open one from ts.

I am able to focus on the right ng-select using the following:

```
@ViewChildren(NgSelectComponent) ngselect: QueryList<NgSelectComponent>;
this.ngselect.last.filterInput.nativeElement.focus()
```

However, I'm not able to open.  I tried the below

```
this.ngselect.last.filterInput.nativeElement.open()
```

but get the error:

```
_this.ngselect.last.filterInput.nativeElement.open is not a function
```

.open() is a method though...how can I get this to work?
https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#methods

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have You tried something like this

```
<ng-select #Selecter ></ng-select>

@ViewChild('Selecter') ngselect: NgSelectComponent;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.ngselect.open();
}
```

Working Example
[Links To stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-36xfyz)

Comment: Thanks, though that gives the same error that I have above.

Comment: Updated my answer with a link to a live example on stackblits

Answer (score 1):

There's a far easier way to achieve what you want. If you check the documentation (found here: https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#api), you'll find you can pass `isOpen` to `ng-select`. Changes to the value of `isOpen` passed to the right `ng-select` would open and close it automatically.

Example:

```
<ng-select
  [isOpen]="isOpen"
  [items]="items"
>
</ng-select>
```

and in the component class, you can simply change isOpen and that would open and close the select.

Comment: Thank you for your help, though I believe that ends up making it a lot more complicated.  Changing isOpen to true makes it so that it won't close (false so that it won't open).  That means I need to also listen for changes.  Since there are multiple selects, I also have to create an array of isOpen to specify the right one.

Answer (score 1):

**You may also need to open it in your test file**, for when you want to check items in the DOM, etc:

**1. Create a file and add this (or add to an existing file if you prefer)**

```
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

/*
* Utils based on ng-select helper functions:
  https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/3018a1098ba2ad06fbdf4dfe60209087cbd68185/src/ng-select/testing/helpers.ts
*/
export function getNgSelectElement(fixture: ComponentFixture<any>): DebugElement {
    return fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('ng-select'));
  }

export function triggerKeyDownEvent(element: DebugElement, which: number, key = ''): void {
  element.triggerEventHandler('keydown', {
      which: which,
      key: key,
      preventDefault: () => { },
  });
}
```

**2. Import the functions into your test file and use them like this:**

```
// Open the dropdown
triggerKeyDownEvent(getNgSelectElement(fixture), 32);
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Comment: You can use the variable selector in the template and run `ngAfterViewInit` manually in your test, but this may be a little too verbose to add to add of your `ng-select` usages, just to test it.

Answer (score 0):

### Use [isOpen]

I want to add some explanation to the answer provided [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55754022/11322237)

`ng-select` has an option to trigger its opening with `[isOpen]="shouldOpenSelect"`

##### Functions you need to define

```js
// .ts file

isAfterFirstOpen = false;

onClickSelect() {
  if (this.isAfterFirstOpen) {
    this.shouldOpenSelect = !this.shouldOpenSelect;
    return;
  }
  this.shouldOpenSelect = true;
  this.isAfterFirstOpen = true;
}

onBlurSelect() {
  this.shouldOpenSelect = false;
  this.isAfterFirstOpen = false;
}

onFocusSelect() {
  this.shouldOpenSelect = true;
}

onChangeSelect() {
  this.shouldOpenSelect = false;
}
```

And

```html
// html file

<ng-select
  [(ngModel)]="value"
  (blur)="onBlurSelect()"
  (change)="onChangeSelect()"
  (focus)="onFocusSelect()"
  (click)="onClickSelect()"
  [isOpen]="shouldOpenSelect"
>
</ng-select>
```