# How to have select options list open / dropped down by default on page load (plain HTML/CSS or Angular solution)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Interestingly, I do not seam to find a simple solution for a simple requirement of having  list of select options open / dropped down on page load.

I am working with Angular 8 in case that offers some simple script, but I was assuming HTML/CSS should have this built in with some property - such as: 'isOpen' or 'isDroppedDown' ...

I see some are resolving it with 'size' or 'multiple', but these change the visual property of the control and I want consistency. The control needs to be/look the same (with the little arrow ...)

Code example: Say we have this list/array in TS/Angular code:

```
  philosophers = ['Aristotle', 'Epicurus', 'Descartes', 'Seneca', 'Plato'];
```

and we feed it to this template:

```
        <select name="phil_selector" [(ngModel)]="selected_phil">
                <option *ngFor="let item of philosophers; index as ix" [value]="ix">
                    {{item}}
                </option>
        </select>

        // For those who prefer plain HTML:

        <select name="phil_selector">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="1">Aristotle</option>
            <option value="2">Epicurus</option>
            <option value="3">Descartes</option>
            <option value="4">Seneca</option>
            <option value="5">Plato</option>
        </select>
```

We do not want any item/philosopher be selected by default, but when the page loads, we want the drop-box be already open, to make it clear to the user, that 1st thing he has to do, is to make his selection from the visible list of options. So he will see this:

[image]

And, he just clicks on his choice and goes on ...

To summarize the requirement - we need to have a list of 'select' options open (dropped down) after HTML page has loaded.

Comment: An alternative that may be easier to implement: show `(Select philosopher)` as the defaut in the select control.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use mat-select of Angular Material you can do it like this:

```js
import {Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic select
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
})
export class SelectOverviewExample implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('mySelect') mySelect;
  foods = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.mySelect.open();
  }
}


/**  Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select #mySelect placeholder="Favorite food">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<br>
<button (click)="click()">click</button>

<!-- Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license -->
```

Or you can try Jquery options like shown here
[How to open select programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609105/how-to-open-select-programmatically)

Comment: For material works good. Thanks. Would be nice to have similar for native HTML elements without much scripting ...

Comment: If error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError. The solution appears to be adding: 'private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef' to constructor and then insert: ngAfterViewChecked() { this.changeDetector.detectChanges();}