# how to fire click listbox event gwt

Tags: java, gwt, listbox, click

I have a listbox. I want to fire a click event which clicks this listbox and we can see the items inside the list.

Things I have tried and did not work-

```
1)   

  DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(Document.get().createClickEvent(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    false, false, false, false), listbox);

2)

 public static native void click(ListBox listbox)/*-{
  listbox.click();
  }-*/;

3)
  DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(Document.get().createChangeEvent(), yourListBox);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but only in chrome.

```
listbox.getElement().dispatchEvent(
    Document.get().createMouseDownEvent(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            false, false, false, false, Event.BUTTON_LEFT));
```

See also [How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due)