# select drop down menu on change event is not happening

Tags: javascript, jquery

With in a from  on selection of stay ours , I am tring to pop up No. of Guests drop down menu  using jquery.

```
<form class="form-inline"  method="get" action="#" th:action="#"  id="search">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="margin:auto;" id="searchlocation">
        <select class="selectpicker form-control" style="margin-left:-1px;" id="stay">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">Stay Hours</option>
            <option value="1">X</option>
            <option value="2">Y</option>
        </select>
        <select class="selectpicker" style="margin-left:-2px;" id="guest">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">No. of guests</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2 </option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4 </option>
            <option value="5">5 </option>
        </select>
        <button type="text" class="form-control btn btn-success" style="margin-left:-1px;">Search</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Jquery :

```
$('#stay').change(function () {

    $('#guest').show(function () {
        $( "#guest" ).focus();
        $( "#guest" ).click();
        $( "#guest" ).select();
    });

});
```

But its not working for me. Can some one help to resolve this ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Programmatically drop down the option list in `#guest`? Please define "not working".

Comment: @Teemu Dropdown menu attached to id="guest"   is not coming after change event happening in id="stay" ? cau you guide me why drop down menu is coming automatically ?

Comment: Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10136523/1169519).

Answer (score 0):

You should change the prop of `guests` to desired index:
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QFdBkoVbYboTkdHd6bDW)

```
$(function() {
  $('#stay').change(function() {
    $('#guest').show(function() {
      $("#guest").focus().prop('selectedIndex', $('#stay').val());
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: yes its working . How can I make drop down come so  that user can  select desire option from given drop down menu?

Comment: but https://www.airbnb.com/ have implemented it. Can you tell me magic behind it ?

Comment: I dont see they have implemented.. If you really want to do that you might want to use custom plugin such as select2 : https://select2.github.io/