# Drop down list after button on click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm relatively new to both HTML and Javascript. I'm trying to figure out how to open a drop down list after clicking on one of two buttons. So far, I have for my buttons:

```
<button id="button1" onclick="button1function()">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="button2function()">Button 2</button>
```

My list for Button 1 so far is

```
<select>
    <option value="jsmith">Jane Smith</option>
    <option value="jdoe">John Doe</option>
</select>
```

And my list for Button 2 so far is

```
<select>
    <option value="iwilliams">Ian Williams</option>
    <option value="arobinson">Andrew Robinson</option>
</select>
```

I'm also curious as to if the drop down list can disappear once you click on the button again.

Thank you all very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due)

Comment: In default hide your select dropdown by setting id  for div and call it in $(document).ready(function(){ $('#id').hide()} ); Then  in onclick function **button1function()** $('#id').show();

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() 
{ 
    document.getElementById('name1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('name2').style.display = 'none';
};

function button1function(id){

    if(document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none'){
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'initial';
    }else{
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
function button2function(id){
    if(document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none'){
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'initial';
    }else{
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>

<button id="button1" onclick="button1function('name1')">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="button2function('name2')">Button 2</button>

<select id="name1">
    <option value="jsmith">Jane Smith</option>
    <option value="jdoe">John Doe</option>
</select>

<select id="name2">
    <option value="iwilliams">Ian Williams</option>
    <option value="arobinson">Andrew Robinson</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for, only on the page load I don't want the drop down lists to be there. Instead, I just want it to be the two buttons there and depending on which button you're clicking on, the drop down list will toggle it's visibility. Any way that's possible?

Comment: @ahuber Yes it is possible. I have edited above code. try that

Answer (score 0):

I have some code for you task:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function emitEvent(element, eventName) {
    var worked = false;
    if(document.createEvent) { // all browsers
      var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
      e.initMouseEvent(eventName, true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
      worked = element.dispatchEvent(e);
    } else if (element.fireEvent) { // ie
      worked = element.fireEvent("on" + eventName);
    }
    if (!worked) { // unknown browser / error
      alert("It didn't worked in your browser.");
    }
  }

  function openDropdown(id){
      var element = document.getElementById(id);
      emitEvent(element, 'mousedown');
  }
</script>

<button id="button1" onclick="openDropdown('name1')">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="openDropdown('name2')">Button 2</button>

<select id="name1">
    <option value="jsmith">Jane Smith</option>
    <option value="jdoe">John Doe</option>
</select>

<select id="name2">
    <option value="iwilliams">Ian Williams</option>
    <option value="arobinson">Andrew Robinson</option>
</select>
```

here is [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mSfMK3toX910W9vTAKpl?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

**A simple modern solution**

This can be done with just a few lines of plain Javascript using [classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to show or hide the drop down. Click Show code and then run snippet to see how it works. There's no reason to load a large library like jQuery unless it is being used elsewhere on the page.

*Also see:*
[How to style a  dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

```js
for (var e of document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown button')) {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    evt.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('open');
  });
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2em;
}
.dropdown select {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
.dropdown.open select {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <select>
    <option>Options 1</option>
    <option value="iwilliams">Ian Williams</option>
    <option value="arobinson">Andrew Robinson</option>
  </select>
</div>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <select>
    <option>Options 2</option>
    <option value="iwilliams">Ian Williams</option>
    <option value="arobinson">Andrew Robinson</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button>Button 3</button>
  <select>
    <option>Options 3</option>
    <option value="iwilliams">Ian Williams</option>
    <option value="arobinson">Andrew Robinson</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>click to toggle the select</div>
```

Javascript

```
// Add a click handler to all dropdowns on the page
for (var e of document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown button')) {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    evt.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('open');
  });
}
```

css

```
.dropdown select {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
.dropdown.open select {
  display: block;
}
```