# Knockoutjs - Open select dropdown on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, dom-events

Is there any way to open a dropdown on clicking some other button?

Comment: When binding the click even, you can just trigger the dropdown of another element in your event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you Go!!

**JS**

```
function VM() {
  var message = ko.observable("hello!!");

  function onButtonClick() {
   var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');    
   showDropDown(dropdown);
}  

function showDropDown(element){
  var event;
  event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
  event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
}

return {
  message: message,
  onButtonClick:onButtonClick
   }
 }

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

**HTML**

```
   <button data-bind="click: onButtonClick">
     Button
   </button>
   <select id="dropdown" >
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option>
     <option>4</option>
   </select>
```

Here's [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/madhu_ranjan/nrxj6qgn/)! with the solution

Updated the solution from [How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due) for Knockout

Comment: Thanks for the help:)

Comment: This does not work anymore with Chrome v. 53.0.2785.116. Any update?