# Force input and select boxes to open downward (not upward) on ipad safari

Tags: html, css, ipad

On my website is an input box where the user inputs date and time and a select box where the user selects how they wish to pay. In safari on iPad the selection boxes are opening like this:

[image]

and

[image]

But I would like for the input / select box to open below instead of above.

I have attached my code below:

HTML

```
<select id="pay-options" class="form-default">
    <option> Pay By Card </option>
    <option> Pay By Cash </option>
    <option> Account </option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
input.form-default{
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the direction that a select element opens. You can create your JavaScript solution using list items, and choose the height and position of your dropdown without depending on html `select`.

Edit-
It seems there is one!
You can check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due) for some attempts to a query quite similar to yours,
and this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fz2sY/39/).