# jQuery Dropdown - drop down options programmatically

Tags: jquery, click, dropdown, html-select

I have a select tag with multiple options. I have a search box for filtering, which hides or shows options depending on what text you type. I want to drop down options the same way it works when I click on it, but I want to do it programmatically. I hope someone understands what I am trying to say.

with other words, while the user is typing something in the search textbox, I want my dropdown element to drop down, the user will be able to see search results while typing...

I have found some examples with `<ul>` and `<li>`, but I want with `<select>` and `<option>`.

HTML

```
<select id="select_street">
    <option value="1">Street 1</option>
    <option value="2">Street 2</option>
    <option value="3">Street 3</option>
    <option value="4">Street 4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="search_filter" />
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
$("#search_filter").on('keyup', function (e) {
        $("#select_street option").each(function () {
            if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().includes($.trim($('#search_filter').val()).toLowerCase())) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due)

Comment: maybe, but with focus() on select, user will not be able to still type in search textbox..

Answer (score 1):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/249219/4202224) this would be the nearest you can get to a solution:

```
$("#search_filter").on('keyup', function(e) {
  $("#select_street").attr('size', $("#select_street option").length);
  //...
});
```

---

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/x1brwp59/)

Comment: and I will apply some fade effects..would be nice. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code does what you want, however you have to start with all options hidden like this:

```
$("#search_filter").on('keyup', function (e) {
    $("#select_street option").each(function () {
        if ($('#search_filter').val() == '') {
            $('#select_street option').hide();
            $('#select_street').val('');
            return;
        }
        if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().includes($.trim($('#search_filter').val()).toLowerCase())) {
            $(this).show();
            if ($('#select_street').val() == '') {
                $('#select_street').val($('#select_street option:first').val());
            }
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
            if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
                $('#select_street').val('');
            }
        }
    });
});
$('#select_street option').hide();
$('#select_street').val('');
```

There reason noone uses select is because you can't open it programatically. My advice is you pick one of these https://www.sitepoint.com/13-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/ don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: well...if I knew that before...thanks! I have work to do know :)