# Open select options from sibling element

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have an select menu with arrow icon next to it. I want to catch the click event of the sibling icon element to open the options of the dropdown.

```html
import React from 'react';

const DropDown = (props) => {
  const options = props.options.map((option) => (
    <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
      {option.displayValue}
    </option>
  ));
  return (
    <>
      <select>{options}</select>
      <box-icon name="chevron-down"></box-icon>
    </>
  );
};

export default DropDown;
```

Comment: This might be a technique to try: https://byprimer.co/blog/style-select-fields-using-css/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is no possible way to open select programmatically. I too found out now. you can check discussion regarding this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due). I advice you to use select libraries like react-select. you can this library documentation [here](https://react-select.com/home). This library has prop "menuIsOpen" change this to achieve your desired result.

Comment: select element doesn't have click event. It doesn't work with focus() either

Comment: sorry i too don't know that click event is not available for select just came across it now. see my edit answer. I hope it will solve your issue.