# Html.DropDownListFor : how to show all options by default

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

Is there a way to show all options in the Select created by the helper Html.DropDownListFor ?

I was searching for the event triggered when you click on the select to show all options to manually trigger but i did not find it.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.Value, 
    Model.Values, 
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:150px;" })
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "show all options" - as it is, your code creates a `select` drop down - none of the items are "hidden" but the drop down does have a maximum height which means some values may need to be scrolled to, but they're still "shown".

Comment: Or do you mean to "open" the `select` either on page load or via some other code?  That's not possible.

Comment: I want the default state of the select would be as if i click once on it.
when i click on it it "shows me all the options", i want the that to be as a default

Comment: yes the word open is more correct

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that's not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due (amongst many other similar questions, more specifically about coding it, but it's essentially the same thing)

Comment: I've found something with the size attribute. WHen defining the size  of the size equal to the number of options it opens all the options by default.

Comment: Yes, that's a select list - it doesn't operate the same was a select drop down (eg doesn't drop over the top of other content / does move around all your other content).  If that works for you, then go for it.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uzcds5v6 to get this in Razor, just add `htmlAttributes: new { size: "5" ...` (or however many lines you want)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a ListBoxFor

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model=>model.Id,model.Values as SelectList)
```