# What event fires after you click on <select> but select no option?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to trigger a cleanup function after `<select>` is opened, but no option is selected and the user clicks away.

I tried `change` and `blur`, but none of them fire.

## Sample and visuals

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');

select.addEventListener('blur', () => {
    console.log('blur');
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
</select>
```

[image: first sate]

I click on the `<select>` and then without selecting an option, I click outside of it. The `blur` event is not triggered until I do a **second** click after the first outside click.

[image: second state]

Comment: As far as i read from here it's not possible.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due

Comment: `blur` seems to work in Chrome..

Comment: The `change` event will not fire unless an option is selected
if you want to fire an event on open then use `focus` event on open and `blur` event on close.

Comment: Have you tried the `click` event?

Comment: Can you describe more precisely what you want to do?

Comment: This seems a bit nebulous... Can you provide a snippet of your code? There's a few ways to approach this but it's based on browser. If you have those specs as well, that would be also be helpful

Comment: @Dom Thanks for the comment, I've reduce the nebula cloud a bit, hopefully, by adding a code sample and screenshots.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? As an user, I **will** expect that the last option I have selected stays selected if I ever do this operation. If an UI were to clear my input when doing this I'd either fill a bug report if I really like the service, or simply stop using the service. Not to mention that it will probably be impossible to get anything cross-browser (for instance I have no idea how screen-readers do render <select>, but I doubt it will fire anything you could be waiting for).

Answer (score 1):

**There's no such event that signifies that the *`<select>` is opened, but no option is selected and the user clicks away.***

However, for `<select>` element, you can bind to `click` event which does not warrant the selection of an option to fire and write custom logic. I just noticed that it requires **2 clicks** on `<select>` element for an option to be selected and for opening it only needs **1 click**. *With the **click** count, we can determine if the preconditions meet and accordingly run the cleanup code:*

```js
var clicks = 0,
    $select = document.getElementById('select');
$select.onclick = function() {
  clicks++;

  if (clicks === 2) {
    clicks = 0;
  }
};
$select.onblur = function(e) {
  if (clicks === 1) {
    clicks = 0;

    // SELECT WAS OPENED BUT NO OPTION SELECTED
    // CLEANUP CODE GOES HERE

    console.log('CLEAN UP');
  }
};
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
</select>
```

Like @leisheng and @Kaiido suggest, this is not universal solution and will only work with desktops and mouse.

Comment: Downvote for using jQuery in a question that does not mention jQuery.

Comment: The select menu can also be opened with the keyboard by using tab to focus and spacebar to open.

Comment: @AdrianBrand Thanks for the feedback. Check the edits. It's pure JS now.

Comment: @AdrianBrand  Kudos, for giving a reason for the downvote,  wish more down-voters did the same, as I believe that is when it becomes helpful.

Comment: @leisheng It's true that keyboard is also used to open the `<select>` but, I was unable to make it work since only `tab` key is registered when the `<select>` comes into focus, subsequent keypresses such as `space` are not fired in the keyboard handlers. If you have something to improve this answer, please feel free to edit.

Answer (score 1):

As far as what events occur when you open a select menu there are many. There may very well be a way to create your own CustomEvent and fire it by tracking the other events. If you can see what events are happening, you might be able to figure something out. This is a script I use to find all events that are occurring on an EventTarget:

```
EventTarget.prototype.__original_addEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(listener, callback) {
    if (listener === 'event') {
        for (let key in this) {
            if (key.startsWith('on')) {
                let eventName = key.substr(2, key.length);
                this.__original_addEventListener(eventName,
                function(e) {
                    callback(e);
                });
            }
        }
    } else {
        this.__original_addEventListener(listener, callback);
    }
};

window.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector('#id-of-my-select-tag').addEventListener('event', (e) => {
        console.log(e.type);
    });
};
```

This just allows you to add a listener called 'event' which captures all events. This will output all the events happening and maybe you will see a pattern that helps you write some code to detect when it is open based on the events that occurred and the order in which they occurred. (Tested in Firefox, Chrome and Edge)

Comment: Thanks for the nice idea how to investigate thism but there appears to be no event that triggers right after.

Comment: Note that not all event listeners do map to an `on...` IDL, for instance `DOMContentLoaded` doesn't.

Comment: @MorganWilde you could possibly chain event listeners to see what events occurred in what order. For example, when a mousedown event occurs, then add an event listener for mouseleave, which appears to be triggered automatically after mousedown on a select tag. The select tag events are a bit confusing because there are many different possibilities. For example, the user can mousedown and then only mouse up once they have selected a different option, so the click event is not reliable for detection. Or they can click, then use the keyboard. You'd have to account for many situations.