# element.click() not working on select element

Tags: javascript

If the try button is clicked should not the options be appeared?

```html
<select id='test1'>
  <option>Option_1</option>
  <option>Option_2</option>
  <option>Option_3</option>
</select>
<button onclick='test1();'>try</button>
<script>
  function test1() {
    document.getElementById('test1').click();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Why should options be appended? Clicking `<select id='test1'>` programmatically has no effect. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to open `select` using `button` ?

Comment: It looks like the `click` event on the `<select>` is indeed invoked, but the event itself isn't what opens the menu.  `<select>` elements are closely tied with native host system functionality, I'm not sure if it's controllable in this manner.  Why are you trying to do this?  You may instead want to replace the `<select>` with a stylized menu.  There are a variety of JavaScript plugins which do this for you, such as ChosenJS or Select2.

Comment: It was possible earlier but now its deprecated.. Please check this :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due

Comment: David, I will automate a task for a website. I want to inject a little program in browser console for a website.@David

Comment: Yes @RapSherlock

Comment: To inject some code in browser console that will automate some task@user4642212

Comment: @Akhil: Interesting find, and potentially a duplicate for this question.  If I were to guess, I suspect in general browsers are reluctant to support dispatching such interactive events from code as it could quickly become a security problem with file inputs.

Comment: @MirajKhondokar: You may need to reconsider your approach for this automation.  What's the underlying goal?  You can *set the value* of the `<select>`, you can *post a form*, etc.  Perhaps you're just going about your goal the wrong way?

Comment: @David: Setting the value of  `<select>` by script does not tiger change event. I need to set the value and tiger the change event for `<select>` element for my so called automation.

Comment: @MirajKhondokar So why not just trigger the `change` event after setting the value?

Comment: Can you set the value and trigger the change event as two separate steps?

Comment: If you change the value manually ( I mean by mouse) then change event is triggered.

Comment: how to do that in two separate steps? I don't know

Comment: @MirajKhondokar 1. Change the `<select>`’s `value`, 2. Trigger a `change` event on the `<select>` element. Googling either of these yields tons of results.

Comment: @user4642212 ohh Understood!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do that.
I suggest when you click the button, it changes to the next option.

```js
function test1() {
    let el = document.getElementById('test1');
    let selectedIndex = el.selectedIndex;
    el.selectedIndex = selectedIndex + 1 === el.options.length ? 0 : selectedIndex + 1
}
```