# Dash React Dropdown Component: Cannot open from Browser Console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly-dash

Running a standard dash-plotly app with a dropdown, I would like to simulate a click on the dropdown via javascript. The dropdown opens when I click on it via the mouse but does not respond to the JS call (`$('#mydropdown.dash-dropdown').click()`).

Any ideas what is going on here?

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html


app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="mydropdown",
            options=[
                {"label": "New York City", "value": "NYC"},
                {"label": "Montreal", "value": "MTL"},
                {"label": "San Francisco", "value": "SF"},
            ],
            value="MTL",
            clearable=False,
        ),
    ]
)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=8099)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is generally not possible anymore in Javascript due to security risks, see [How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/249192/2146052).

Testing click events can be performed via Selenium instead.