# React JS dropdown add scrollbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

code:

```
<select>
  <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
  <option value="lime">Lime</option>
  <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
  <option value="mango">Mango</option>
</select>
```

i am new to react and implemented drop down successfully
i like to add below function to drop down

1.add vertical scrollbar
2.keep open drop down by default

any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: use react-select component https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select, for documentation and available options https://react-select.com/

Comment: @sojin thanks for reply.i like to implement it without npm help

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple perfect answer to both of your questions. The `<select>` element is notoriously difficult to style productively with CSS and its internal structure is complex, and hard to control. But there's some workaround:

1. When there're many options in the `<select>`, it will add a scroll bar automatically
2. Trigger a click event through javascript, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10136523/6416061)

Comment: "If you want to get full control, you should consider using a library with good facilities for styling form widgets, or try rolling your own dropdown menu using non-semantic elements, JavaScript, and WAI-ARIA to provide semantics."

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#styling_with_css

Comment: i have to implement search with dropdown.
library providing search option with input field which i do not want.
link you shared to trigger click event not working for me

Comment: I meant you should consider using a component library rather than implementing it by yourself. If you do need to do this, read their documents or even source code first.

Comment: Like this: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/dropdown. They always provide enough props for your customized requirement