# Open a select element to show the options list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have been looking around this problem all day but can't find a solution, only people who say it is not possible. Is it really not possible to open a select to show the options programmatically from a JavaScript file?

I have tried to click on it with `document.getElementById('mySelect').click();` but nothing happens. I can however use `document.getElementById('mySelect').focus();` to focus on the element.

Is there really no way in 2023 to open a select from JavaScript? If so, why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you programmatically tell an HTML SELECT to drop down (for example, due to mouseover)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due

Comment: @Taxel, So only possible in Chrome? Why is this? How hard is it to drop it down? :)