# How to open the option list of select using JS in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-quill

I want to open the options dropdown of select on an external icon component click

[image]

I'm using react-quill, the select dropdown already comes with an undesired icon that i hide using

```
display:none
```

then I added my customized icon component `<MyIcon />` , but the problem is when i click on the icon nothing happens.

So I created an `onClick` function **on the surrounding dev** to fire a click() on the **select tag** to open up.

But not working.

```
 <div
    className="editor-dropdown"
    onClick={() => {
      let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementsByClassName(
        'ql-header',
      )[0] as HTMLElement;
      element.click();
    }}
  >
    <select
      className="ql-header"
      id="fontsize-select"
      defaultValue={'4'}
      onChange={(e) => e.persist()}
    >
      <option value="1">Heading 1</option>
      <option value="2">Heading 2</option>
      <option value="3">Heading 3</option>
      <option value="4" selected>
        Normal
      </option>
    </select>
    <MyIcon />
  </div>
```

Comment: Check this question and quite many answers under it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249192/how-can-you-programmatically-tell-an-html-select-to-drop-down-for-example-due

Comment: I tried some of the solutions there, didn't work for me.

Comment: Check [this](https://moderncss.dev/custom-select-styles-with-pure-css/) out.  There is a runnable demo at the bottom of the page.